# not able to fetch json correctly from curl call?

Tags: php, json, parsing, curl

A dummy script that reponds with some json..

```
<?php

$result['code'] = 200;
echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

However when I make a curl call to this script,trying to fetch json response and then convert it to array..things go wrong.

Usually I do a simple json_decode($json) and it gives me an array,but apparently when I `var_dump json_decode($json)` , it gives me `int(1)` as response. I simply want to fetch the code from the json.

This is my code :

```
public function curlcall($username, $msg)
{

    $url           = 'someurl.php';
    $fields        = array('username' => $username, 'message' => $msg);
    $fields_string = null;
    foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {$fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';}
    rtrim($fields_string, '&');
    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();
    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo '-------------------------';
    var_dump($result);
    exit;
}
```

When I directly call the script from rest client, it gives me perfect json response. But when I request the same json via curl, I dont get the desired result while converting that json in to array.

For simplicity sake, I just echoed a string but still when I `var_dump` it,it gives me `int(1).`

Comment: Try putting the `$result` into a `.txt` file and see the direct result that the curl server sent. Maybe there is an error some where that is not being displayed in the rest client

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

Comment: I think that without the RETURN_TRANSFER OPT the response does not return to your variable

Comment: Okay, I just added that  it gives me string(0) "". Earlier it was returning as int(1)

Comment: Can you add the (full) code in the script you are posting to?

Comment: What is the result of var_dump before json_encode() is executed?

Comment: I just added a header and return transfer that was metioned by you guys and things worked. thx.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //NOTICE this line, which says you want a response returned to the calling script
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo '-------------------------';
    var_dump($result);
```